How to catch all emails in exchange when sent to dynamic email with wildcard
Good day everyone
I am trying to do something together with power automate and exchange server but somehow the process is failing. I have created the following email
inbox.patient@myhospital.noneofyourbusiness

and I wanted to configure a mail flow rule that whenever the labs outside the hospital would send some report, they would email it to for example
inbox.patient.322@ myhospital.noneofyourbusiness 

or 

inbox.patient.319@ myhospital.noneofyourbusiness


and redirect it to inbox, where  the power automate would parse it and do the rest of the work…
however every time I try to send it, I always get email addresses not found.

Solved it. I was not making the domain with internal Relay.
